# Boundary Homomorphism (2)

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, exact-sequence, ring-homomorphism

I am dealing with this proposition ([Boundary Homomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003158/boundary-homomorphism)):

> Let
>   $$
> \require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> 0 @>>> M^{'} @>{u}>> M @>{v}>> M^{''} @>>> 0 \\
> @. @V{f^{'}}VV @V{f}VV @VV{f^{''}}V \\
> 0 @>>> N^{'} @>{u^{'}}>> N @>{v^{'}}>> N^{''} @>>> 0
> \end{CD}$$
>   be a comutative diagram of $A$-modules and homomorphisms, with the rows exact. Then exists an exact sequence:
>   $$\cdots\stackrel{\bar{v}}\longrightarrow Ker(f^{''})\stackrel{d}\longrightarrow Coker(f^{'})\stackrel{\bar{u}^{'}}\longrightarrow\cdots.$$
>   Where the *boundary homomorphism* $d$ is defined as follows: if $x^{''} \in Ker(f^{''})$, we have $x^{''}=v(x)$ for some $x \in M$, and $v^{'}(f(x))=f^{''}(v(x))=0$, hence $f(x) \in Ker(v^{'})=Im(u^{'})$, so that $f(x)=u^{'}(y^{'})$ for some one $y^{'} \in N^{'}$. Then $d(x^{''})$ is defined to be the image of $y^{'}$ in $Coker(f^{'})$.

And have the following doubty:

> $d(v(x))=0\iff\\ y'\in Im(f')\iff \\\overline{u}'(y'+ Im(f'))=0\iff \\u'(y')+Im(f)=0\iff \\u'(y')=f(x)$

for some $x \in M.$

But this holds for any $v(x),$ so could $d$ be the null homomorphism...?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disregard my previous answer: the problem is in the second logic equality of your reasoning. For one of the implications you are using that $\overline{u}'$ must be injective which is false, even if the starting $u'$ is mono. If you consider the derived long exact sequence injectivity of $\overline{u}'$ is equivalent to $d$ being the zero map as you deduce.

Comment: Sorry, I am with troubles and difficulties: where did I use $\overline{v}$? I just could see that I always will have $d(v(x))=0$ and always $d(x'')$ is at form $d(v(x))$, so I just could see $d\equiv 0$. I know I am wrong and you right, but I could not understand. Could you help me once again please? Many thanks.

Comment: Once the lines are exacts, $v$ is surjective, so all element of $ker(f'')$ is at form $v(x)$, what do you think? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes... $\overline{u}'$ is not injective. Many thanks!